# hg-ssh - cannot clone repository, but pull/push works

Tags: linux, ssh, mercurial

I am trying to setup a new mercurial server (first time for me), serving with hg-ssh and am running into the problem that I can pull and push, but not clone a repository to the server.

In .ssh/authorized_keys on the server, I have the following line before the key:

> no-pty,no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,command=".../hg-ssh
>   repos/*"

Without this line, cloning the repository works, so it's not a path issue.

I am somewhat baffled by this, because I would have expected hg-ssh to allow for cloning - am I wrong in assuming this?
Is there some config I might have missed?

Comment: What errors you see in the log? What do you see if you try to `ssh` to this account with this key? `.../hg-ssh repos/*` does not sound right. What about the `...`? I am not sure if the wildcard works here.

Comment: Sorry, the wildcards was me editing out the full path for posting here, should have mentioned that.
Cloning fails with 'Illegal command "hg init [path]'".

Comment: That would be good idea. You might omit something that you consider unrelated, but it is crucial for the functionality

Comment: Checked connecting via ssh with my key, this seems to work fine as far as I can tell. I don't get a shell due to the settings above, but this is expected.

Comment: perhaps in addition to `hg-ssh` you should also allow `hg`, don't you think? checkout this https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2009-July/027021.html

Comment: Adding hg itself to the allowed ssh commands is not necessary. The only part where I'm unsure is whether you can clone *to* the server without authorizing hg itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to determine from the documentation whether hg-ssh should allow cloning *to* the server.

What I have done is change the line

```
command=".../hg-ssh repos/*"
```

to

```
command="[path]/allowed-commands.sh
```

and implemented the script following https://serverfault.com/a/803873, redirecting all 'hg init' calls to hg directly, while redirecting all pull/push requests to hg-ssh.

This works fine for pull/push and clone.